# Reset vertex name counter in tkz-berge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-berge

I have a following graph constructed with `tkz-berge` library. In the current settings the nodes/vertices are numbered automatically started with index 0. I wonder how to reset the counter in order to start with 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
\SetUpVertex[Math,Lpos=-180,LabelOut]
\SetVertexNormal[FillColor=red,OuterSep=0pt]
\grEmptyPath[form=2,x=0,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=u,Math]{5}
\SetUpVertex[Lpos=0]
\SetVertexNormal[FillColor=blue]
\grEmptyPath[form=2,x=6,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=v,Math]{4}
\Edges(u4,v3,u3,v2,u1)
\Edges(u3,v3,u0,v0,u2,v1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node counter is used throughout the code of `tkz-berge` to calculate positions and to generate internal node names, so when you change the counter all kinds of things break down. However, you can renew (i.e., modify) the lower level node printing command `\write@math` which calls `\Vertex` (defined by the package `tkz-graph`, which is loaded by `tkz-berge`) with the node label as one of the arguments. Using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` you can add 1 to the node counter, store the result in a macro, and print that macro in the label instead of the counter itself. Note that `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` should be used instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro` to avoid adding `.0` in the label.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\write@math}[3]{%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\printindex}{#3+1}
            \Vertex[x = #1,y = #2,%
                    L = \cmdGR@cl@prefix\grMathSep{\printindex}]{\cmdGR@cl@prefix#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
\SetUpVertex[Math,Lpos=-180,LabelOut]
\SetVertexNormal[FillColor=red,OuterSep=0pt]
\grEmptyPath[form=2,x=0,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=u,Math]{5}
\SetUpVertex[Lpos=0]
\SetVertexNormal[FillColor=blue]
\grEmptyPath[form=2,x=6,y=0,RA=2,rotation=90,prefix=v,Math]{4}
\Edges(u4,v3,u3,v2,u1)
\Edges(u3,v3,u0,v0,u2,v1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!